# How to compare date from integer?

Tags: python, datetime

I am using the following piece of code to get today's date

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
year = now.year
month = now.month
date1 = now.day
if(date1 >= 8):
    -------
```

In the `if` condition it is giving error which is -

> '>=' is not supported between instances of 'built_in_function_or_method' and 'int'

Now how to compare it ??

Comment: What is the _purpose_ of this comparison, in plain English?

Comment: do you mean `day` or `date`?

Comment: `now.date` is the function itself. You should change it to `now.date()` at the very least.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is `8` supposed to represent? What specifically are you trying to do? Your question as written now is like asking "How do I compare this apple  to that table?", and clearly that makes  no sense. Neither does trying to compare a date (a combination of a month, day, and year) to a single integer (what is that integer supposed to be - a month, a day, a year, the number of toes on your cat's front paws?).

Comment: Sorry that was day @-Ken White and I want to compare the current date to 8 of that month to run apply further conditions

Comment: Sorry to all Now I got my answer I was attempting mistake @Azat Ibrakov  . After using now.day code is running perfect

Answer (score 2):

you probably want to use a `timedelta` object, and/or a `date` object.

A timedelta object represents a duration, the difference between two dates or times.

Here is an example for what you seem to look for:

```
datetime.date(2017, 5, 18) < datetime.date.now() # returns True
datetime.date(2017, 5, 17) - datetime.date(2017, 5, 18) # returns datetime.timedelta(-1)
```

- The first operation returns a boolean operator.
- The second operation returns a negative number (the difference in days) as 18th May 2017 comes after 17th May 2017.

Note that timedelta takes the following arguments (according to Python doc):

```
class datetime.timedelta([days[, seconds[, microseconds[, milliseconds[, minutes[, hours[, weeks]]]]]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean `day` ? Cause you wrote `date` which is a `datetime` function that converts a `datetime.datetime` to a `datetime.date` object.

Answer (score -1):

I am guessing that you are looking for:

```
datetime.timedelta
```